# How to validate number of input parameters in an expect shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I'm trying to validate the number of arguments in a shell script I'm creating.
The script will be using expect.

**Error**

```
invalid command name "$#"
    while executing
"$# -ne 3 "
    invoked from within
"if [ $# -ne 3 ] then"
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
if [ $# -ne 3 ] then
   echo "Wrong number of arguments provided"
   echo "fgrep_host.sh hostname filter_text new_file"
   exit
fi
```

Comment: When you are writing a pure `expect` script, you should not use the bash commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dinesh said, an `expect` script is **not** a shell script, it's an `expect` script, which is `Tcl`.

To do what you want, you'd write it:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
if {$argc != 3} {
  puts "Wrong number of arguments provided"
  puts "fgrep_host.sh hostname filter_text new_file"
  exit 1
}
```

(*though you shouldn't be adding the `.sh` extension*)

You're going to have to read up on `expect` and `Tcl` to continue.

Comment: Thanks!! First time writing an expect script.